# clang fails autoconf AC_CHECK_HEADER checks with explicit CPPFLAGS search paths

Tags: compiler-construction, include, llvm, clang, autoconf

In an established autotools-managed project which is almost always built with GCC, I decided to try using LLVM clang as a g++ substitute, but found that it falls over on a personally-written header check that uses the standard AC_CHECK_HEADER macro. Here's the checking code:

```
oldCPPFLAGS=$CPPFLAGS
CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I$GSLINCPATH"
AC_CHECK_HEADER([gsl/gsl_vector.h], [], [AC_MSG_ERROR([GSL vectors not found.])])
CPPFLAGS=$oldCPPFLAGS
```

and here's the failure message:

```
checking gsl/gsl_vector.h usability... no
checking gsl/gsl_vector.h presence... no
checking for gsl/gsl_vector.h... no
configure: error: GSL vectors not found.
```

The value of $GSLINCPATH is /usr/include (explicitly checked), /usr/include/gsl/gsl_vector.h does exist, and this check code works nicely with GCC. The temporary switching in of a modified $CPPFLAGS seems to be the de facto standard way to do this test, but is there a better way that is more portable? Or is there another reason for this problem?

Comment: What is the output of config.log around this check?

Comment: Ah, good call: it seems that the command line message is a bit misleading:

    configure:15294: clang++ -c -O2 -I/usr/include -I/usr/include conftest.cpp >&5
    In file included from conftest.cpp:61:
    In file included from /usr/include/gsl/gsl_vector.h:4:
    In file included from /usr/include/gsl/gsl_vector_complex_long_double.h:25:
    In file included from /usr/include/gsl/gsl_errno.h:24:
    In file included from /usr/include/errno.h:36:
    In file included from /usr/include/bits/errno.h:25:
    /usr/include/linux/errno.h:4:10: fatal error: 'asm/errno.h' file not found

Comment: Sorry about the layout above: code formatting isn't possible in comments? Oh well.

So gsl/gsl_vector.h _is_ found, but the includes eventually lead to asm/errno.h, which isn't. clang/GSL compatibility problem? Thanks.

Comment: If code formatting is possible in comments, I haven't figured it out yet either :-).  Anyway, the method you use to substitute flags generally works.  I use it.  The problem is the missing header (somewhere in errno.h) the error is complaining about.  Should clang be pulling in includes from /usr/include?  Or does it have it's own place for system files?

Comment: Aha, this seems to be a bug (or at least a package dependency wrinkle) in Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/clang/+bug/774215 Installing the gcc-multilib package fixes it. Cheers :)

Comment: Why would you do the test this way?  If you append required values to CPPFLAGS during configury, then configure will pass but make will fail.  The user should be setting CPPFLAGS as necessary to build on the system.  If the compiler cannot find the header file because the user has installed the header in a strange place and has not added to CPPFLAGS, then the user wants configure to fail.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, it's a _test_, i.e. it's being used to check whether something works in principle -- if it passes, then some extra logic is executed. In automake builds, the right thing to do is to append to AM_CPPFLAGS, which will then be prepended to CPPFLAGS in the generated Makefiles. I would say that it's also quite reasonable (indeed desirable in many cases) for configure scripts to show some intelligence in e.g. trying to figure out paths without the user having to explicitly specify them before calling configure: it all depends on the context, of course.